# ¿Cómo usar dangerouslySetInnerHTML en literales en REACT?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

Quisiera inyectar unos `br` en un componente REACT (en este caso el componente Popup del final), se que no es buena práctica pero no encuentro otra forma, el caso es que probe con la propiedad `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` de varias formas pero no obtengo resultado, aqui dejo el codigo:

```
return (
    <>
      {!position ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <MapContainer center={position} zoom={13}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          <Marker position={position} icon={userMarker}>
            <Popup>Estas aquí!!</Popup>
          </Marker>
          {petShops.map((el) => (
            <Marker
              key={el.name}
              position={[position[0] + el.lat, position[1] + el.lon]}
              icon={petMarker}
            >
              <Popup
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "<br>" }}
              >{`${el.name}<br>${el.adress}<br>${el.city}`}</Popup>
            </Marker>
          ))}
        </MapContainer>
      )}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: ¿El componente `<Popup>` tiene  declaración, de dónde viene?

Comment: @g.4 es de la libreria leaflet para manejo de mapas

Comment: okay, ¿En la documentación de `<Popup>` mencionan que se puede personalizar?

Comment: @g.4 no lo se, intui que era como en las etiquetas jsx normales. De lo contrario, habria otra manera de meter un retorno de carro sin usar dangerously...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finalmente he dado con la solucion y sin usar dangerouslySetInnerHTML:

```
<Popup>{`${el.name}`}<br />{`${el.adress}`}<br />{`${el.city}`}</Popup>
```

era bastante sencillo, y como casi siempre di con ello cuando no estoy sentado en la compu

Answer (score 1):

Por favor intenta la siguiente configuración para `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
<Popup dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `${el.name}<br>${el.adress}<br>${el.city}`}}>
</Popup>
```

De mi lado, funciona bien con `div` en vez de `Popup`.

#### Notas de campo

En la documentación de React se menciona que la usar `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, se puede exponer al usuario a ataques tipo Cross-site scripting.

Comment: lamentablemente no funciona...gracias de todos modos!!